# How to implement vertical stacked bar chart using recharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, recharts, stacked-bar-chart

I want to implement a stacked vertical bar charts using recharts.
and I have added output graph view I have tried a lot of sample json and also I am beginner in graph implement should anyone help me to solve this and how need sample JSON to get attached graph view

Requirements:->
bar fill is with respect to the current date and shows them in percentage  below I am attached output view of graph

**See this graph output view** --->
[graph view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAHZs.png)

I have tried with some examples and edit some parts but the graph not getting as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add vertical layout property to the bar graph. Here is basic code to create vertical bar graph using recharts.

```
<BarChart
 width={730}
 height={250}
 data={data}
 barCategoryGap={1}
 margin={{ top: 0, right: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
 layout="vertical"
>
 <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
  <XAxis type="number" hide />
   <YAxis
    type="category"
    width={150}
    padding={{ left: 20 }}
    dataKey="name"
   />
    <Tooltip />
    <Legend />
    <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
    <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
</BarChart>
```

Comment: thx for your reply but I want to show the graph like that I am attached above. please check and can you help me to how to implement with mentioned sample JSON to the desired result or we can change JSON accordingly for getting result if neccessary